# REST Web Service 400 error when calling function

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I have made a REST Web service, that works with Visual Studios WCF Test Client. 
Can call it with a website that sits next to it and uses a "proxy" class that was created with svcutil.

I can also see the service is there when I Browse to the .svc file. (http://localhost/service1.svc) It comes up with the "You have created a service." webpage.

HOWEVER

When i try and call a function within the service, (http://localhost/service.svc/firstName/lastName) it returns a 400 error code.

I recently had seperate error that I couldn't figure out so I found a tutorial on a VERY basic web service " http://blog.weareon.net/how-to-create-and-consume-rest-web-service-using-wcf/ ", that one stopped the previous error, but still has the 400 error when trying to call a function.

My .config file was cut back to the bare bones to try to get it work before i get in too far.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="VService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceName.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>        
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"  />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, Error"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "SdrConfigExample1.e2e" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

In my research, I have found things like, proxy settings in the browser, return types, size issues, but none have worked so far.

If you have any ideas, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

this is the XML from the log file, thanks for the comments to let me know this exists :)

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-02-15T03:24:00.9952760Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="3128" ThreadID="4" />
<Channel />
<Computer>ACKZ-01</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>9b0666f2-9-129737498327838293</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.CreateMessage()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.CreateMessage()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</ExceptionString>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Haven't completely studied it yet, thought I would post it at the same time

EDIT 2

CODE FROM THE SERVICE

```
namespace VeryBasicService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate="/{firstname}/{lastname}")]
        string CallRestService(string firstName, string lastName);      


        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
```

CODE OF THE FUNCTION

```
namespace VeryBasicService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
        public string CallRestService(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            return firstName + " " + lastName;            
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your event log shed any light on what is happening?

Comment: You will want to turn on WCF tracing and use the trace tool http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx to get a more detailed error.

Comment: Thanks, See Update :)

Says System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty. Is that comming from the browser end or server?

Comment: Can you post your code that calls the service?  If the server is saying that the client is sending an empty request, then the problem may be on that end.

Comment: The code is from the tutorial that is linked above. In the browser (using IE 9) "http://localhost:49401/Service1.svc/firstName/LastName" I will update the above in a second with services code

Comment: Can you also please post your IService interface (The service contract where you define the operation contracts). You can change the names of the methods, but keep the names of the arguments and any attributes intact.

Comment: See above :) Most of this code is what is used in my webservice. I will replace this with what has come from the Tutorial service, although this is basically IDENTICAL! - Code Updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems I can see in your code. First, the name attribute of the `<service>` element in web.config is only listing "serviceName" - if this is not the **fully-qualified name** of the service class, it won't be used. Second, you shouldn't use `WebInvoke` for GET requests, you should use `WebGet` instead:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/{firstname}/{lastname}")]
```

Comment: What would be a fully-qualified name for the service class? I am very new to web services, so still trying to get my head around some thing. Also was origionally WebGet, still same thing unfortunatly.

Comment: A fully-qualified name would include the namespace.  `MyNamespace.ClassName`

Comment: Thanks. All information helps. The code in the question has changes slightly, would this work as the name? 

<service name="VeryBasicService.Service">

Comment: Appologies, it would be more <service name="VeryBasicService.Service1"> as service1 is the class. Or would it be .IService1?

Comment: Through some playing with the service name and the endpoint contract, i was able to find the right place for everything. THANK YOU! this little bit of information has helped me ALOT. Thanks to Tung, Jacob, Jared and M.Babcock also for the help :D